# Install mod_perl.so for XAMPP Windows

Tags: php, perl, xampp, apache2.4

I want to install Perl for XAMPP on Windows. I'm following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ocsinventory-ng.org/index.php?title=Howtos:Install_OCS_on_WAMP#Apache_configuration) for OCS Inventory. But when running the following command :
`ppm install http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/mod_perl-2.0.ppd` I get an error :

> ppm install failed: 500 Can't connect to theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca:80 (Bad hostname)

How can I fix this ?
I'm using XAMPP with Apache2.4 and PHP 5..6.